# How to publish and subscribe .pdf file in Google Pub/Sub (GCP)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In the below code the big .pdf file is split into single pages and uploaded into bucket and enqueued to pubsub simultaneously

```
    def publish_messages(project_id, topic_id, enqueue_file):
    
        publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
        topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
    
        data = enqueue_file
            # Data must be a bytestring
        data = data.encode("utf-8")
            # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
        future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)
        print(future.result())
    
        print(enqueue_file + "has been enqueued to Pub/Sub.")
    
    
    def upload_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):
            assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
            for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
                if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
                    continue
                remote_path = os.path.join(gcs_path, local_file[1 + len(local_path) :])
                storage_client = storage.Client()
                buck = storage_client.bucket(bucket)
                blob = buck.blob(remote_path)
                blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
                print("Uploaded " + local_file + " to gs bucket " + bucket)
                publish_messages("Project1", "my-topic", local_file)
```

I receive messages using the below code

```
def receive_messages(project_id, subscription_id , timeout=None):
    from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

    def callback(message):
        print("Received message: {}".format(message))
        message.ack()

    streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print("Listening for messages on {}..\n".format(subscription_path))
    
    with subscriber:
        try:
            streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    receive_messages("Project1", "my-sub")
```

But when I receive I am getting just string data.

```
Received message: Message {
  data: b'/tmp/doc_pages/document-page17.pdf'
  ordering_key: ''
  attributes: {}
}
```

My idea is to get that pdf file and perform some OCR operation using Vision API. Is it possible to get pdf file itself? Is there any other methodology please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to use Cloud Pub/Sub? Notice that you could simply read this file from the bucket itself as explained on the [Cloud Vision OCR documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#document_text_detection_requests) using a Cloud Function and the code described on the previous link. I think a better approach could be to use a Cloud Function that is triggered by [object finalize trigger type](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) and avoid the use of Cloud Pub/sub at all.

Comment: Is reading those pdfs inside Vision OCR what you need? If yes, you dont need PubSub for that. Please let me know more details about what you need

Comment: My requirement is.. I am creating a kubeflow pipeline.. when component 1 splits a page from pdf document an event should be triggered to component 2 so that it can start processing some OCR on it instead have to wait for component 1 to finish splitting of entire pdf document? Something like event driven..